# Google maps search for points within a specified distance

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to build a google map app that has some functionality based on user input. So i have this large fusion table with a lot of wikipedia articles related to a geopoint. I am trying to have a user input an address and the show the results within 3 or 10 miles from the search point. Here is my Code. First problem i have is i cant clean the existing markers when i search and then i need to show the results.Any idea on how to do it?
The direction part works great.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style>
   html, body, #map-canvas {
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px
   }
   #panel {
     position: absolute;
     top: 5px;
     left: 50%;
     margin-left: -180px;
     z-index: 5;
     background-color: #fff;
     padding: 5px;
     border: 1px solid #999;
   }
 </style>
 <style>
   #directions-panel {
     height: 100%;
     float: right;
     width: 390px;
     overflow: auto;
   }

   #map-canvas {
     margin-right: 390px;
   }

         .dirhead{
             background-color: rgb(30, 113, 160);
             color: white;
             font-size: 25px;
             padding: 10px;
         }

   #control {
     background: #fff;
     padding: 5px;
     font-size: 14px;
     font-family: Arial;
     border: 1px solid #ccc;
     box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.4);
     display: none;
   }

   @media print {
     #map-canvas {
       height: 500px;
       margin: 0;
     }

     #directions-panel {
       float: none;
       width: auto;
     }
   }
 </style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script
            src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js">
        </script>
    <script
            src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map-canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1');
    var map;
    var directionsDisplay;
    var geocoder;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var markers = [];
function initialize(lat,lng) {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        var lat = 39.50;
        var lng = -98.35;
        var bounds;
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var markerClusterer = null;
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));

  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
    zoom: 6,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
    mapOptions);
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
     // var query = "SELECT wikipedia_article,location FROM 1NICsBtZWfpi3kF_3OHsDe7Z9CU2biwyx_A4HRg";
//         query = encodeURIComponent(query);
        var control = document.getElementById('control');
        control.style.display = 'block';
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(control);
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
                 loadmapHere(map,infoWindow,"regular");
        });
}


    function loadmapHere(map,infoWindow){
            var swPoint = map.getBounds().getSouthWest();
            var nePoint = map.getBounds().getNorthEast();
                console.log(swPoint);
                console.log(nePoint);
            // Now, each individual coordinate
            var swLat = swPoint.lat();
            var swLng = swPoint.lng();
            var neLat = nePoint.lat();
            var neLng = nePoint.lng();
              var query = "SELECT wikipedia_article,location FROM " + '1NICsBtZWfpi3kF_3OHsDe7Z9CU2biwyx_A4HRg where ST_INTERSECTS(location, RECTANGLE(LATLNG('+swLat+', '+swLng+'),LATLNG('+neLat+', '+neLng+')))';
          var encodedQuery = encodeURIComponent(query);

         // Construct the URL
          var url = ['https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query'];
          url.push('?sql=' + encodedQuery);
          url.push('&key=key here);
          url.push('&callback=?');

              $.ajax({
           url: url.join(''),
           dataType: 'jsonp',
           success: function (data) {
             var rows = data['rows'];
             for (var i in rows) {
               var wiki_article = rows[i][0];
               var position = rows[i][1];
               var location = position.split(' ');
               var lat = location[0];
               var lng = location[1];
               var positioni = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
               var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                             map: map,
                 position: positioni,
                 icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Map-Markers-Icons-Demo-PNG/32/Map-Marker-Ball-Pink.png'),
                             customInfo: wiki_article
               });
                         markers.push(marker);
                         google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function(e) {
                             infoWindow.setContent('Wiki Link: <a href="'+decodeURIComponent(this.customInfo)+'" target="_new">'  + decodeURIComponent(this.customInfo) + '</a>');
                             infoWindow.open(map, this);
                                 document.getElementById('destination').value = this.position;
                         });
               }
                         markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
             }
         });
        }

        function showMeNear() {
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var address = document.getElementById("milesAddress").value;
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'tilesloaded');
                    hideMarkers(map,markers);
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
                        query: "SELECT Address FROM 1NICsBtZWfpi3kF_3OHsDe7Z9CU2biwyx_A4HRg WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(location, RECTANGLE(LATLNG(37.3, -122.3), LATLNG(37.6, -121.9)))"
                      });
                      layer.setMap(map);
          } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
          }
        });
      }


        function calcRoute() {
          var start = document.getElementById('initAddress').value;
          var end = document.getElementById('destination').value;
          var request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
          };
          directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
              directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
          });
        }

        function hideMarkers(map, markers) {
    /* Remove All Markers */
    while(markers.length){
        markers.pop().setMap(null);
    }

    console.log("Remove All Markers");
    }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="control">
        <strong>Search for Articles in:</strong>
        <select id="milesMenu">
          <option value="3">3 miles</option>
          <option value="10">10 miles</option>
          <option value="17">17 miles</option>
          <option value="25">25 miles</option>
        </select>
         from <input type="text" id="milesAddress" placeholder="Enter Address"><button class="showNear" onclick="showMeNear()">Go</button><br />
          <strong>Get Directions from here:</strong><input type="text" id="initAddress" placeholder="Enter Address"></input><input id="destination" type="hidden" value=""></input> to the clicked marker <button class="givemeRoute" onclick="calcRoute()">Go</button>
    </div>
    <div id="directions-panel"><div class="dirhead">Directions Here</div></div>
<div id="map-canvas"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you create thousands of markers instead of using a FusionTableLayer?

Comment: I guess i dont know how to create a table layer.

Comment: The documentation is here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables . You have to define your query, the style(in your case the iconName of the markers) and the template for the InfoWindow. The API will create everything automatically(e.g. markers with their InfoWindows). Queries may be changed dynamically to apply a filtering depending on user-input. The benefit: there aren't thousands of google.map.Markers, the markers will be rendered via the Layer-tiles.